# Какой именно установочный диск качать для установки?

Tags: debian

Решил попробовать Debian Squeez. Подскажите, какой dvd диск качать, их там несколько, насколько я понял, мне достаточно скачать первый диск, остальное можно потянуть из инета. Архитектура 32-битная. Так правильно ли я понял, что нужен первый двд диск?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Диска №1 хватит. Языковые пакеты докачаются из интернета. Ещё нужно будет самому прописать репозитории.

Answer (score 0):

Если с интернетом проблем нет, то обычно используют версию [netinstall](http://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/). Вот, например, для ленивых [debian-6.0.4-i386-netinst.iso](http://mirror.yandex.ru/debian-cd/current/i386/iso-cd/debian-6.0.4-i386-netinst.iso) сразу ))